# Symfony / Doctrine: OneToMany insert results in null id

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.8

I have two entities that I'm trying to apply a OneToMany / ManyToOne relationship to (one Game has many GameContent).

**Game**

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="GameContent", mappedBy="game")
 */
private $contents;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->contents = new ArrayCollection();
}

public function getContents()
{
    return $this->contents;
}
```

**GameContent**

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Game", inversedBy="contents")
 */
private $game;
```

And the following code inserts both records into their respective tables:

```
$game = $form->getData();
$content = new GameContent();
$content->setType('some type');
$game->getContents()->add($content);

$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$em->persist($content);
$em->persist($game);
$em->flush();
```

However, the GameContent's `game_id` is inserted as `null`:

```
INSERT INTO game_content (type, game_id) VALUES (?, ?)
Parameters: { 1: 'some type', 2: null }
```

I've also tried:

- changing the order of `persist()`
- replacing `$game->getContents()->add($content)` with `$game->addContents($content)` by doing `$this->contents[] = $content;`
- removing `persist($content)` and having `cascade={"persist"}` on the Game entity.

Why is `game_id` being inserted as null?

---

My current workaround is:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$game = $form->getData();
$em->persist($game);

$content = new GameContent();
$content->setType('some type');
$content->setGame($game);
$em->persist($content);

$em->flush();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 solutions :

**Persist children in controller**

Without `cascade={"persist"}`

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

// Get data
$game = $form->getData();

// Create new GameContent and hydrate
$content = new GameContent();
$content->setType('some type');

// Associate Game <> GameContent
$content->setGame($game);

// Persist GameContent
$em->persist($content);

// Persist Game and commit
$em->persist($game);
$em->flush();
```

**Persist children in cascade**

With `cascade={"persist"}` in OneToMany relation.

Add in `setGame()` function, to force association :

```
$game->addContent($this);
```

And remove persist :

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

// Get data
$game = $form->getData();

// Create new GameContent and hydrate
$content = new GameContent();
$content->setType('some type');

// Associate Game <> GameContent
$content->setGame($game);

// Persist Game and commit
$em->persist($game);
$em->flush();
```

I think the error was also due to the positioning of the persist on game.

Comment: Ah, so I was missing `$game->addContent($this);` in order to cascade.

Is either solution generally preferred?

Comment: BTW, the positioning of persist on game didn't seem to matter (see my "workaround" which is the same as your first solution, but with persist in a different order).

Answer (score 1):

> Add in setGame() function, to force association :
>
> ```
> $game->addContent($this);
> ```
>
> And remove persist :
>
> ```
> $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
>
> // Get data
> $game = $form->getData();
>
> // Create new GameContent and hydrate
> $content = new GameContent();
> $content->setType('some type');
>
> // Associate Game <> GameContent
> $content->setGame($game);
>
> // Persist Game and commit
> $em->persist($game);
> $em->flush();
> ```

Note that today (Doctrine 2.7.1), the make:entity utility creates methods that does this stuff for you, in your case you would have had a method like this on your Game entity:

```
public function addContent(GameContent $content): self
{
    $this->contents->add($content);
    $content->setGame($this); // <-- IMPORTANT PART IS HERE

    return $this;
}
```

Then, calling this on the game would have done the job:

```
this->addContent((new GameContent())->setType('some type'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Further to the accepted answer, my next step was to create a form to handle the GameContent data, which led to further changes and some simplified logic.

I now `setGame()` in `Game::addContent()`, and so I've removed `$game->addContent($this);` in `GameContent::setGame()`.

**Game**

```
/**
 * @var ArrayCollection
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="GameContent", mappedBy="game", cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $contents;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->contents = new ArrayCollection();
}

public function getContents()
{
    return $this->contents;
}

public function addContent(GameContent $content)
{
    $this->contents->add($content);
    $content->setGame($this);

    return $this;
}

public function removeContent(GameContent $content)
{
    $this->contents->removeElement($content);

    return $this;
}
```

**GameContent**

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Game", inversedBy="contents")
 */
private $game;

public function setGame(Game $game)
{
    $this->game = $game;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return Game
 */
public function getGame()
{
    return $this->game;
}
```

The real-world form-handling logic will look like this:

```
$game = $form->getData();
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$em->persist($game);
$em->flush();
```

More information at: http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/form/form_collections.html (see *Doctrine: Cascading Relations and saving the "Inverse" side*).